# add dynamic data inside database using dynamic array JSP

Tags: html, mysql, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I have to add data inside my database, after a dynamically created table from the user containing 2 columns which are (ID,Name)

how can i retrieve data of each single user-inserted row and add them to my database

Note that am doing a JSP Page and the most important is to take values which are submitted inside the form

you can check the code below:

```
    <h1 align="center">Please Select How many countries to add </h1>
    <form action="addCountry.jsp" method="post">
        <input name="nbCountry" placeholder="Number of Countries To Add" class="inputText" style="margin-left: 480px; width:300px;text-align:center" type="text"><br><br>
        <input value="ADD" class="inputText" style="margin-left: 600px;" type="submit" align="middle">
    </form> <br><br><br> 

    <%           String nbCountry = request.getParameter("nbCountry");
        int numCountry = 0;
        if (nbCountry != null && !nbCountry.isEmpty()) {
            numCountry = Integer.parseInt(nbCountry);
        }
        int countryid[] =new int[numCountry];
        String countryName[] = new String[numCountry];
    %> 


    <table border="1" align="center" height="300" width="250" style="text-align:center">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">Country ID</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">Country Name</td>
        </tr>
        <% while (rst.next()) {%>
        <tr><td><%=rst.getInt(1)%></td><td><%=rst.getString(2)%></td></tr>
        <% }
                for (int i = 0; i < numCountry; i++) {%>
        <tr>
        <form action="addCountry.jsp" method="post">
            <td width="30" height="30"><input type="text" name="<%=countryid[i]%>" style="text-align:center"><%=countryid[i]%></td>
            <td width="30" height="30"><input type="text" name="<%=countryName[i]%>" style="text-align:center"><%=countryName[i]%></td>
        </form>
           </tr> <% }%>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="add" style="width: 100%"></td></tr>
    </table>

    <%    stmt.close();
            dbConnection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    %>

</body>
<%@include file="footer.jsp"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mmentioned errors you are facing. And the code you submitted is not complete one. Anyway, I found some problem in your  code, correcting this might help you.
"style="text-align:center"><%=countryid[i]%>
             style="text-align:center"><%=countryName[i]%>

I have removed the double quote from the name  attribute  value of input tag, which will set the exact value of name attribute.